# Can't register new client on Instagram developers page

Tags: instagram

I'm trying to register a new client on Instagram developers page. After filling the form with the web page, phone number, and description, I'm getting a blank page that says:

"Sorry, an error occurred while processing this request.".

Not sure if it's a problem with the system or with my account.

Any hint?

Comment: Can you call them? If so, do so!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because [so] isn't Instagram's customer support.

Comment: Instagram api is currently down. None of the websites using api is functioning so this isn't something you did, it is instagram being instagram.

Comment: having the same problem! you would think with a billion dollars they could get this this correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem with Instagram server. 
I have one API, on my website, and it not work more. And some times show 502 error.

And the error: "Sorry, this page could not be found."

I don't know why. But website like a web.stagram.com have the same problem.

If you try login (on [web.stagram.com](http://web.stagram.com) for exemple), and go to https://instagram.com/accounts/manage_access the aplication/api, the app from Stagram is not allowed and is not on the list.

I think is a problem with API system. And a Captcha on Instagram have the same error too.

Sorry for my English.

- the web.stagram.com, is only for example, because is a big website.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.   I'm pretty sure the instagram API servers are down right now.

Comment: I am having the issue- "Sorry we could not register you right now. Our developers will look into it." any idea?